# Facebook chat on website

Tags: facebook, facebook-chat

Is it possible for a website to have facebook chat integrated into it, but only show the friends which are on the same site/page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes
use facebook graph protocol to get friend of the user
and the user who in the page in already in your databse
and joining between the two by the uid

im sorry fvor my poor english